# Glade gtk drag and drop tools

Tags: python, gtk

`Glade` is a program to create windows, panels, buttons...

My question is does `glade` provide the tools to write apps for drag and drop.
I've gone through the tools on the left side and couldn't find anything relating to a dropbox or droptext!?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Glade does not provide tools to write code. It just creates a "template" for placing Gui and gui related objects. Not the code that will place them on screen.

But you can connect the required signals inside glade so that will be easy to connect them in your code. Which signals and what you will do with these signals is upon you.